# Ex 4.1.10 from topology without tears

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

Let (Y $\tau_y$) be a subspace of (X $\tau$)

Show $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau$ iff Y $\in \tau$

(Hint :Y$\in\tau_Y$)

**Rewrite of proof with help from others**

Let $\tau_Y$={$O\cap Y$: $O\in\tau$}

(=>) Assume $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau$

Let $Y\in \tau_Y$ $\exists$ Y open in X s.t Y $\cap X$=Y
as X $\in\tau $ So Y$\in \tau_Y\subseteq\tau$ Thus Y$\in \tau$

(<=) Let Y $\in \tau.$ Let U=$\tau_Y$ be arbitrary open set of Y

As Y,O $\in\tau, \exists O\in Y$ s.t O$\cap Y$=U So U$\in\tau$.

Since U is arbitrary $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument for $(\Rightarrow)$ simply doesn’t make sense. You write:

> $O\cap Y$ implies that $(O\cap Y)\cap Y\subset(O\cap X)\cap Y$
>
> Thus $Y\in\tau$

First, $O\cap Y$ is not a statement, so it cannot imply anything. Secondly, the fact that $Y\subseteq X$ alone is enough to imply that $(O\cap Y)\cap Y$ and $(O\cap X)\cap Y$ are both equal to $O\cap Y$, whether or not $Y\in\tau$, so the conclusion that $Y\in\tau$ is a *non sequitur*.

The hint actually tells you how to prove this implication: $Y=X\cap Y$, and $X\in\tau$, so by definition $Y\in\tau_Y$. For this implication you’re assuming that $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau$, and you know that $Y\in\tau_Y$, so $Y\in\tau$. That’s all there is to it.

Your argument for $(\Leftarrow)$ is stated clumsily enough that I can’t tell for sure whether you have the right idea; here’s a cleaned up version.

> Suppose that $Y\in\tau$. Let $U\in\tau_Y$ be arbitrary; then there is an $O\in\tau$ such that $U=O\cap Y$. And $O$ and $Y$ are both in $\tau$, so $U=O\cap Y\in\tau$. Since $U$ was an arbitrary member of $\tau_Y$, $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau$.

Comment: Actually l was thinking of that ,but l thought it could not be that easy

Comment: @Homer: This time it really is that easy.

Comment: If $\tau_y \subset \tau$ O$\in \tau$ and Y$\in \tau...$

Comment: @Homer: … and $\tau$, being a topology, is closed under finite intersections, so $O\cap Y\in\tau$.

Comment: I got my ideas on how to do my proof from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/622212/830852

Comment: @Homer: The proof given in the question there is correct but far too wordy; the proof in the accepted answer is a much better presentation of essentially the same reasoning and is a much better model. Note, though, that the result being proved there is quite different from the one that you’re working on.

Comment: I am rewriting it with accepted answer model . Gawd l feel so dense 

Answer (score 0):

First, the forward direction, $\implies$, is much simpler than you are making it to be (and the argument you give is nonsensical): since $\tau_Y$ is a topology on $Y$, then $Y\in\tau_Y$. If $\tau_Y\subseteq \tau$, then $Y\in\tau_Y\subseteq \tau$, so $Y\in\tau$. Done and done.

Second: what you are "supposing" in the backward direction, $\Longleftarrow$, is **not** correct. You do not "suppose"  that the equivalence of "$Y\in \tau$"  and "$Y$ is open in $X$". That's not a supposition. That's a **definition**. What you need to assume is that $Y\in\tau$. Just that.

Then you are trying to prove that $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau$, and you start with something in $\tau$... well, no. You need to prove that if $A\in\tau_Y$, then $A\in\tau$. *You never do that*. So, you are correct: something is missing, namely, the proof of the "if" part. Instead, you seem to be arguing that if $O\in\tau$, then $O\cap Y\in \tau\cap\tau_Y$; that does not prove what you want to prove. All you are arguing (since we already know that $O\in\tau_Y$ by definition) is that if you assume that $Y$ is open is open in $X$, and $O$ is open in $X$, then $O\cap Y$ is open in $X$. But we know that just from the properties of topological spaces; you aren't proving anything about the subspace topology.

How do the proof of the $\Longleftarrow$ part?  You want to prove $\tau_Y\subseteq \tau$, so you should start by taking something in $\tau_Y$ and proving it is in $\tau$.

To that end, let $A\in\tau_Y$. That means that $A=\mathcal{O}\cap Y$ for some $\mathcal{O}\in\tau$. Now you need to show that $A$ is in $\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is happening in your attempt to be honest. But I feel like it is much simpler than you might think, especially if you take the hint into account.

$"\Rightarrow"$: Suppose that $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau$. We have that $Y \in \tau_Y$, either by using the hint or by writing $Y = Y \cap X$, as $X \in \tau$. Then we have that $Y \in \tau_Y \subseteq \tau$, therefore $Y \in \tau$.

$"\Leftarrow"$: Suppose now that $Y \in \tau$. Let $A \in \tau_Y$ be an arbitrary open set of $Y$. So we can write $A = O \cap Y$ for some $O \in \tau$. Now we have that $A$ must also be in $\tau$ since it is the finite intersection of elements in $\tau$. Since $A$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau$.

Comment: So in proving it l have assign a variable to O$\cap$ Y

Comment: I guess you mean the $\Leftarrow$ direction? I wouldn't say 'assign a variable'. What you want to do is show that $\tau_Y \subseteq \tau$. When you have to show such a thing, it's almost always going to follow the same 'pattern': take an arbitrary set in $\tau_Y$, which I decided to call $A$, and show (in general by using the hypothesis you have, here $Y \in \tau$) that this set $A$ is also in $\tau$, i.e. $A \in \tau$. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: So no need of mentioning open sets ok...

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the usage of 'open sets' in topology. If we have a topological space $(X, \tau)$ we call $\tau$, which is a collection of subsets of $X$, a topology on $X$. Not any collection is a topology, the basic axioms must be satisfied ($X, \emptyset \in \tau$, closed under arbitrary unions, closed under finite intersections). Now we simply say $A$ is open for the sets $A \in \tau$. So in my explanation, when i say take $A \in \tau_Y$, i could have said 'let $A$ be an open set of Y'. But I think it's more clear the way i wrote it. So I **did** mention open sets.

Comment: @Homer If this is all totally confusing to you, i suggest that you go back to the definition of a topology in your script and reread the chapter there. Otherwise you might not really be able to do any exercises since these basic concepts are really important to understand.

Comment: I understand the basic axioms. I understand open sets. Open set consists of the members of a topology. Also every open interval is an open set but not vice versa . Union of open sets/intervals is an open set – script? Point set topology as far I know was not taught in university when I went. After basic analysis course which I aced, there is the course called Real Analysis (advanced analysis course) using Royden’s Real Analysis,which is an measure theory text. The only topology course was algebraic or geometric topology.

Comment: With 'script' I was referring to 'Topology without tears', which you mention in your title. But I must admit that 'book' might have been a better choice of words. Also, I'm not trying to belittle you or anything, I was just trying make a suggestion. Topology is a field with a decent level of abstraction, so it is sometimes a little hard to grasp in the beginning for many people (including me!). I'm happy to help / answer further questions if it's any help to you.

Comment: Definitely me as l am tripping over my own feet and it sucks and me feel like l am collapsing in on myself & lose confidence in doing this stuff